# NSTask to call command top. Getting Error

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos

intelligent people!

Thanks so much for checking out my post.

Right now I'm running this:

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/top"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-stats", @"pid,cpu", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
//The magic line that keeps your log where it belongs
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];
```

and it is giving me the error:

```
 Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

Any clues? Thanks again!

Comment: Why are you setting its standard input? The comment doesn't adequately explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if it was my arguments:

```
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-s", @"1",@"-l",@"3600",@"-stats",@"pid,cpu,time,command", nil];
```

Thanks!